# How to write the return in multiple lines

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

The following function has many items in the returned tuples:

```
def test_real():
    return (item_a_long_name, item_b_long_name), (item_c_long_name, item_d_long_name), ..., (item_x_long_name, item_y_long_name)
```

It is hard to see all the contents in the `Jupyter Notebook Cell` as the `return` will display in a `single line`.

The following code is trying to `split` the `return` items:

```
def test():
    return (1,2), (3,4)

print("test:", test())

def test2():
    return (
        1,2
    ), 
    (
        3,4
    )

print("test2:", test2())
```

**Here is the output:**

```
test: ((1, 2), (3, 4))
test2: ((1, 2),)
```

The `test2` is not work as expected.
How to write the correct `return` in the `test2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add extra parenthesis to wrap the return properly then the return is spread across multiple lines.

```py
def test():
    return (1,2), (3,4)

print("test:", test())

def test2():
    return ((
        1,2
    ), 
    (
        3,4
    ))

print("test2:", test2())
```

```py
# output
test: ((1, 2), (3, 4))
test2: ((1, 2), (3, 4))
```